# taking a join with output of other sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables as follows `T1 and T2.`

```
T1 has one field as A  and T2  has one field B.
```

Now i want to do following: for each value of `T1.A` I want to join with `T2.B`

Something like :

```
select * from T1 ,(select * from where T2 where T2.B = T1.A)
```

Is this correct? When i try this I get an error saying `T1.A is invalid indentifier`.

I know that i can do `select * from T1,T2 where T1.A = T2.B`

But my use case is very complex. The query (`select * from where T2 where T2.B = T1.A`) is very complex.

So how do I go ahead with this?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to `JOIN` the tables:

```
select * 
from T1 
inner join T2 
  on T2.B = T1.A
```

If you need help learning `JOIN` syntax, here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

I used an `INNER JOIN` which will return the rows that match between `T1` and `T2`. You might need to use a `LEFT JOIN` which will return all rows in `T1` even if there is not a matching row in `T2`

If you have another query to select from, then you can use a subquery:

```
select * 
from T1 
inner join
( 
   -- place your query here
   select *
   from T2
) T2 
  on T2.B = T1.A
```

If your subquery is only returning one column, then you could use:

```
select t1.*, (select t2.col1 from T2 t2 where t2.B = t1.A) 
from T1 t1
```

Comment: I know , I already mentioned in my original post.But the second table is not a table it is output of some complex query.Please read end part of post

Comment: But the subquery it self needs T1.A to be used inside it.

Comment: Can you post your actual query?

Comment: sorry ,no , against my company policies :(

Comment: can u help me with answer rohit suggested?

Comment: @user93796 you cannot use a value from your `T1` inside a query or in a query that is going to return multiple columns. If you are only returning one column, then you could use something similar to my edit.

Comment: if your requirement is selecting multiple columns, what prevents you from using @bluefeets solution? Is there some constraint?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm mistaken, can't you just use `JOIN`:

```
select * 
from t1 
join t2 on t1.field = t2.field
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
select * 
from T1 
inner join T2 
  on T2.B = T1.A
```

as other people have said.
However, this "ON" version is preferred only for readability.

You can also go ahead an use

```
select * from T1,T2 where T1.A = T2.B
```

The optimizer will figure it out, and do the exact same thing,
as the queries are equivalent.

You can go ahead an use it, as there is nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from first_table inner join second_table on first_table.X = second_table.Y
```

Answer (score 0):

select A,T1.B,(select * from where T2 where T2.B = T1.A) FROM T1 .Will this help?

Comment: i get error i get error saying T1.A is invalid indentifier. while trying this

Comment: select T1.A,T1.B,(select COL3 from  Tab2 AS T2 where T2.COL3 = T1.A) FROM Tab1 T1 is working for me in MS-SQL 2008

Comment: Oops. I didnt realise you were using Oracle